# Storing Specific data on DB Table(s)

Tags: data-structures, database-theory

I have an Excel with 40columns and 20k rows, and i have to store it in a database but i cant figure the best approach for it, the excel format is like this:

This table has 30 columns for days, then 11 columns for the next 11 weeks and then 9 columns for the next 9 month, in resume the first month is in days the next 3 months are in weeks and the rest of the year is in months.

Each column has the number of pieces that i need to produce certain product in that span of time.

```
Part number | 1/1/2018 ||||| 30/1/2018 | Week6 ||| Week16 | Month4 ||||||Month12
PART1             2             5          10        12        40          50
PART2             3             4          13        11        50          70
PART3             4             3          13        15        60          60
PART4             1             3          16        12        40          30
```

This Excel file has to be pasted in to a datagridview and then save it in a DB,
should i use 1 table or more? what shold be my table design to store this data?

Comment: What table design are you considering?

Comment: There's not enough information in your question to make it reasonably answerable here.  We would need to know more about your problem domain to come up with a sensible table design.  Offhand, though, I'd say that your design isn't sufficiently *normalized.*

Comment: @koverman47 i had this idea of using a for to go thru all the datagrid and save all the qty column by colun and row by row but since there are like 50 columns * 15000 rowsit will be = 750,000 saves on the database and i dont know if thats the best way to do this

Comment: Define "best".  "Best" under what criteria?  Without listing specific requirements or evaluation metrics, this comes down to a matter of opinion.  The appropriate table might depend on what you want to do with the data and what operations you want to perform on it.  Also, usually the most helpful way to respond to comments is to consider how to improve your question, and edit it to incorporate additional information (don't just leave information/clarifications in the comments; we want people to be able to understand what you're asking by reading the question).

Comment: Cross-posted: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/375943/34181.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my mind when you start using a "DB" I'm assuming that you mean a relational/SQL database, and then the design of how the information is stored might change entirely.

It seems like you're using this Excel file to track a master production schedule for some kind of parts manufacturing, so it's how many parts you need, and when you need them by.

I'm not sure it makes sense to have multiple time scales in the same table for that purpose. So my reflex would be to say, we should create a table that stores information about, the date, how many parts need to be produced on that date, and which part needs to be produced.

```
CREATE TABLE production_schedule (
    prod_date date,
    part_no   int,
    part_qty  int
);
```

Then if you need to build reporting or gather the information about how much in a week, a month, six months, or a year. You could do that with queries when you need that information or you could create views that are based on such queries.

For example, a query like the following would return the total amount of parts to be created in January 2018.

```
SELECT SUM(part_qty) FROM production_schedule WHERE prod_date BETWEEN '01/01/2018' AND '31/01/2018';
```

Hopefully, this helps you understand the way you should think about creating a database to solve your problems, and perhaps a verbatim transfer of the information isn't the best solution.

It can help when getting started to think of databases as spreadsheets because they store information in a way that can be thought of as "column and row". The fact that you can store information in them and also ask sometimes simple and sometimes complicated questions of them can throw off people who are new to working with databases.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i ended up using a design really close to the one you posted here, the problem im havign is with the way i recive the information, i recive an Excel file with the format i state above and thats why i am having problems since i cant control the format of the input.

Comment: Are you able to work with the provider to figure out their needs and express how you can best help them?